# Google Play Console: how to start closed beta group?

Tags: android, google-play

We want to start a closed beta group, but the state in Google Play Store won't change to this.

This is how it looks like regardless wether we set it up or not:

[image]

After clicking on "setup closed beta" this view is shown:

[image]

We already added two testers and after it clicked on *"submit update"* in the right top corner.

And also we've uploaded an APK to the beta test:
[image]

Then for one 'til two hours the state will be "processing update", and after this time the state *"processing update"* will not be displayed any more, but the page looks like the first image i've provided above after refreshing.

Comment: Did you upload an APK to Beta?

Comment: Yes. I will add a screenshot to the question

Comment: Screenshot provided right now

Comment: Looks like you cant do this anymore. From Play Console Help --> Note: You can no longer create open alpha or closed beta tests. You'll retain access to any existing open alpha or closed beta tests that are already in progress.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found it and can answer myself:

one have to checkmark at least one tester email to enter the closed beta group. Then it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you cant do this anymore. From Play Console Help --> Note: You can no longer create open alpha or closed beta tests. You'll retain access to any existing open alpha or closed beta tests that are already in progress.